# Having Clause issue - returning wrong data

Tags: mysql

I am a bit stuck with a problem I have been working on and would appreciate some help.  I believe I should be using a HAVING clause, but can't figure out how to get it working properly.  As opposed to showing several members, it shows 1 member and adds everything up.

The query should list each customer where the total detail rental fee is greater than twice the overall average detail rental fee. The output should be sorted by membership number.

Mem_num mem_fname  mem_lname Total)detail_fee
103 Curt        Knight          7.50
105 Iva     Mclain          7.00
110 Lewis       Rossale         9.00
111 Stacy       Mann            9.00

```
select m.mem_num, mem_fname, mem_lname, sum(detail_fee), avg(detail_fee)
from membership as m, rental as r
left outer join detailrental as d on (r.rent_num = d.rent_num)
group by detail_fee
having sum(detail_fee);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.mem_num, mem_fname, mem_lname, sum(detail_fee) as sum_fee, avg(detail_fee) as avg_fee
from membership as m, rental as r
left outer join detailrental as d on (r.rent_num = d.rent_num)
group by mem_num
having sum_fee > 2 * avg_fee;
```

The query above is a bit "righter" than yours. Problem is this:

```
from membership as m, rental as r
```

This is a cross join. Meaning, each row in membership is connected with each row in rental. This will give you wrong results I guess. Is there no connection between these 2 tables? Something like

```
from membership as m 
inner join rental as r 
on m.id = r.member_id
```

?

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Here is the finished product that worked. select m.mem_num, mem_fname, mem_lname, sum(detail_fee) as Total_Detail_Fee, avg(detail_fee) as avg_fee
from membership as m
inner join rental as r on m.mem_num = r.mem_num
left outer join detailrental as d on (r.rent_num = d.rent_num)
group by mem_num
having Total_Detail_Fee > 2 * avg_fee;

Comment: @user1331726 When this answer helped you, you can accept and/or upvote it.